# How to get the value of a capacitor in series if I have the total value

Tags: capacitor

I have 2 capacitors in series. 1st capacitor's values is 24.5uF. The total value of both capacitors are 16.5uF. How to calculate the value of the second capacitor?

The formula to calculate the total value of capacitors in series.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the formula for capacitors in series?  Do you have basic algebra skills?  If the answers are yes, you already know how to solve the problem, if no, let us know which one you are missing...

Comment: @DeanFranks I have the equation for in series, but I do lack the knowledge of Algebra.

Comment: So, fill in the values you have (one of the capacitors and the total) and add it to the question, it will be off topic for Electrical Engineering, but I'll answer it anyway...  If you are an EE major (speculating from the question), you might want to reconsider that choice as an EE degree is very very very math intensive.

Comment: @DeanFranks I'm not in electrical engineering field. I haven't used Algebra for 25 years. I added the formula of the capacitors in series to the question. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ C_T = \frac 1 {\frac 1 {C_1} + \frac 1 {C_2} + ...} $$

Inverting ...

$$ \frac 1 {C_T} = \frac 1 {C_1} + \frac 1 {C_2} + ... $$

If \$ C_1 \$ is unknown then

$$ \frac 1 {C_1} = \frac 1 {C_T} - \frac 1 {C_2} - ... $$

Solve that and invert the result to get \$ C_1 \$.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm adding resistors in parallel or caps in series by hand with a calculator, I enter the following sequence ...

C1, x<sup>-1</sup>, C2, x<sup>-1</sup>, +, x<sup>-1</sup>

To find the component needed to bring the combination to the desired total, the sequence is almost the same, note the minus sign ...

desired total C, x<sup>-1</sup>, initial C, x<sup>-1</sup>, -, x<sup>-1</sup>